# What is the probability that all priorities are unique for Permute-By-Sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, probability

I hope someone can help me answer the following question. Thanks!

Here is a pseudo code of Permute-By-Sorting algorithm:

```
Permute-By-Sorting (A)

    n = A.length

    let P[1..n] be a new array

    for i = 1 to n

        P[i] = Random (1,n^3)

    sort A, using P as sort keys
```

In the above algorithm, the array P represents the priorities of the elements in array A. Line 4 chooses a random number between 1 and n^3.

The question is what is the probability that all priorities in P are unique? and how do I get the probability?

Comment: I'm torn on whether this would be better suited for Math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You are choosing `n` numbers from `1...n^3` and asking what is the probability that they are all unique.

There are `(n^3) P n = (n^3)!/(n^3-n)!` ways to choose the n numbers uniquely, and `(n^3)^n` ways to choose the n-numbers total.

So the probability of the numbers being unique is just the first equation divided by the second, which gives

```
     n3!
--------------
 (n3-n)!  n3n
```

Comment: This answer is also wrong. `n^3 C n` is relevant when order doesn't matter, but here it does.

Comment: Now your answer is just like the one below, and even though you fixed the denominator issue, your index is still off by 1. Also, your explanation is inaccurate, since there are `n^(3n)` ways of choosing the numbers in total, not non-uniquely.

Comment: @davin: *"index is off by one"* - care to explain what you mean by that?  I am fairly certain the equation is correct.  Also, I've fixed your picky semantic issue *(even though it's obvious what I mean by "non-unique")*.

Comment: Off by one from what I was doing in my head (I have a slightly different, although equivalent, counting method), but having looked at your values they're fine. Apologies. I'm not so sure what I said was picky. I do often nitpick, but there is an important difference between counting permutations and counting unique/non-unique permutations.

Answer (score 1):

To reconcile the answers already given: for choice i = 0, ..., n - 1, given that no duplicates have been chosen yet, there are n^3 - i non-duplicate choices of n^3 total for the ith value. Thus the probability is the product for i = 0, ..., n - 1 of (1 - i/n^3).

sdcwc is using a union bound to lowerbound this probability by 1 - O(1/n). This estimate turns out to be basically right. The proof sketch is that (1 - i/n^3) is exp(-i/n^3 + O(i^2/n^6)), so the product is exp(-O(n^2)/n^3 + O(n^-3)), which is greater than or equal to 1 - O(n^2)/n^3 + O(n^-3) = 1 - O(1/n). I'm sure the fine folks on math.SE would be happy to do this derivation "properly" for you.

Answer (score 1):

Others have given you the probability calculation, but I think you may be asking the wrong question.

I assume the reason you're asking about the probability of the priorities being unique, and the reason for choosing n^3 in the first place, is because you're hoping they will be unique, and choosing a large range relative to n seems to be a reasonable way of achieving uniqueness.

It is much easier to ensure that the values are unique. Simply populate the array of priorities with the numbers 1 .. n and then shuffle them with [the Fisher-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (aka algorithm P from The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2, Seminumerical Algorithms, by Donald Knuth).

The sort would then be carried out with known unique priority values.

(There are also other ways of going about getting a random permutation. It is possible to generate the nth lexicographic permutation of a sequence using factoradic numbers (or, the factorial number system), and so generate the permutation for a randomly chosen value in [1 .. n!].)

Answer (score 0):

So the sort part is irrelevant

Assuming the "Random" is real random, the probability is just

```
      n^3!
----------------
 (n^3-n)!n^(3n)
```

Comment: You're counting correctly, but your answer is wrong. Firstly, it's not in the range [0,1], which should jump out at you, so you're not dividing by the sample space size. Secondly, you're indices are slightly off.

Comment: @davin thanks for your hint! so i think i should divide that by n^3n, however i don't understand your second point, can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: -1: n^3!/(n^3-n)! is larger than 1, not a probability. Its inverse (n^3-n)!/n^3! grows slower than 1/n^3, so it cannot be the correct answer.

Comment: @sdcvvc you are right, see our comments above, i guess i need to update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Let A<sub>ij</sub> be the event: i-th and j-th elements collide. Obviously P(A<sub>ij</sub>)=1/n<sup>3</sup>.

There is at most n<sup>2</sup> pairs, therefore probability of at least one collision is at most 1/n.

If you are interested in exact thing, see BlueRaja's answer, but in randomized algorithms it is usually enough to give this type of bound.

Comment: Your math is correct, although 1/n is a very poor bound practically speaking, especially since not too advanced math shows that the tight bound is much much **much** stricter. In practise, I disagree that 1/n is acceptable when the real bound can be bounded far better than exponentially (almost factorially).

Comment: It is not exponentially better, 1/n^3 is a trivial lower bound.

Comment: On the probability. 1/n^3 <= P <= 1/n.